# Maximum quantity per order magento not per product

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shopping-cart

I want to set maximum quantity per order not per product. I tried to set the
System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart to 3, as per requirement only 3 item per order, The problem is when I tried to add 9 items 3 per product it is allowed. What I want is just to set 3 on whole cart regardless of item.
Does anyone know a way to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I already found alternative on this. My scenario is i want to limit the order in 5 quantity only. I dont know if it is the right way but it is working to me.

Go to app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php

in function indexAction() put below code;

```
$count = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
if (abs($count) > 5) {
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($this->__('You have exceed the maximum quantity for this order. Maximum quantity per order is 5.'));
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    return;
}
```